# Tabulator cell span

Tags: html, cell, tabulator

I have a couple of tabulator tables in our project.
My goal to do cell span after one cell was edited.

For example:

- A user did value change
- I check "cellEdit" callback
- If my condition is true - do cell span

How to acheive this?

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 3):

Tabulator currently does not offer cell span functionality, this will be coming in version 5.0